# PHP - sort nth-level subarray

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, nested, sub-array

Let's suppose I've a nested PHP array `$aaa` where
the entry `$aaa[$bbb][$ccc]` is like

```
array(0 => array('x' => 3, 'y' => 2), 1 => array('x' => 2, 'y' => 1), 2 => array('x' => 4, 'y' => 1))
```

and let's say I want to order just this array by `x` value in order to get the array

```
array(0 => array('x' => 2, 'y' => 1), 1 => array('x' => 3, 'y' => 2), 2 => array('x' => 4, 'y' => 1))
```

and not modify all the other subarrays.
How can I do it? I'm not able to do it with `usort` and a custom function.

Comment: what is your expected result? show this

Comment: "I'm not able to do it with usort and a custom function" Why not?

Comment: I've properly modified the question, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: The code usort($aaa[$bbb][$ccc], 'compare_func'), where compare_func($a, $b) compares 'x' values of $a and $b, doesn't work

Comment: I have submited my answer. Please check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yet it *can* be done with `usort`

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array('x' => 3, 'y' => 2),
    1 => array('x' => 2, 'y' => 1),
    2 => array('x' => 4, 'y' => 1)
);

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['x'] == $b['x']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['x'] < $b['x']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arr, "cmp");

var_dump($arr);
```

Result

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["x"]=>
    int(2)
    ["y"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["x"]=>
    int(3)
    ["y"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["x"]=>
    int(4)
    ["y"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`usort` *is* an easy way to do this (not clear why yours wouldn't have worked), and if you're using PHP 7, It's a great opportunity to use one of the new features, `<=>`, the [combined comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op), (AKA the spaceship).

```
usort($your_array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['x'] <=> $b['x'];
});
```

> The spaceship operator is used for comparing two expressions. It returns -1, 0 or 1 when $a is respectively less than, equal to, or greater than $b.

(If you're not using PHP 7, then of course you can still use `usort` with a different comparison function, or other approaches, as the other answers here have shown.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use with `usort` like bellow :

```
<?php  
function compare_func($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
}

$name = array(0 => array('x' => 3, 'y' => 2), 1 => array('x' => 2, 'y' => 1), 2 => array('x' => 4, 'y' => 1));
usort($name, compare_func('x'));
print_r($name);
?>
```

Output : `Array ( [0] => Array ( [x] => 2 [y] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [x] => 3 [y] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [x] => 4 [y] => 1 ) )`

For more details http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have defined `$bbb` and `$ccc` as the keys;  extract the `x` keys from the array and sort that, sorting the original array:

```
array_multisort(array_column($aaa[$bbb][$ccc], 'x'), $aaa[$bbb][$ccc]);
```